# Bootstrap 3 Navbar with Icons & Carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on creating a site with bootstrap3. Unfortunately, even after watching many videos I am still having problems.

1. I would like the logo on my navbar to remain on the left side (which I have) and other additional icons that will be links to other area of the page to be toward the left - unfortunately I have not figured this out via html/css. Please check out www.frobot.net to see what I am attempting to emulate. Essentially, there are multiple icons next to the text.
2. I would like a white background for the navbar and for it to have a definitive bottom rather than meshing into the rest of the website, if that makes sense. As of right now, there is not a consistent horizontal white area with the navigation tools.
3. I set up a carousel for three images and only the first image appears.

Can someone please point out issues in my code?

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
        <head>

             <!-- Website Title & Description for Search Engine purposes -->
            <title>THE BEST YOGURT</title>
             <meta name="description" content="Frozen Yogurt">

        <!-- Mobile viewport optimized -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

        <!-- Include Modernizr in the head, before any other Javascript -->
        <script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>


    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="container" id="main">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <div class="navbar-header">

                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">

                            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="#Logo">

                        </a>

                    </div>

                    <div class="navbar navbar-custom">

                        <div class="navbar-header">

                            <a class="icons" href="icons">

                    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

                    <a href="#"><img src="img/froyo.png" alt="Froyo"<li>FROYO</li></a>

                    <a href="#"><img src="img/story.png" alt="Bots"<li>BOTS</li></a>

                    <a href="#"><img src="img/team.png" alt="Press"<li>PRESS</li></a>

                    <a href="#"><img src="img/talk.png" alt="Team"<li>TEAM</li></a>

                    <a href="#"><img src="img/contact.png" alt="Contact"<li>CONTACT</li></a>

                </div>

            </nav><!--End Nav Bar -->

        </div>

        <!-- Carousel Begins -->

        <div class="carousel-slide" id="myCarousel">

            <!-- Indicators -->

            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
                <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
                <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active" id="slide1">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h4></h4>
                        <p></p>
                    </div><!-- end carousel-caption-->
                </div><!-- end item --> 

                <div class="item" id="slide2">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h4></h4>
                        <p></p>
                    </div><!-- end carousel-caption-->
                </div><!-- end item -->

                <div class="item" id="slide3">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h4></h4>
                        <p></p>
                    </div><!-- end carousel-caption-->
                </div><!-- end item -->
            </div><!-- carousel-inner -->

            <!-- Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel"><span class="icon-prev"></span></a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel"><span class="icon-next"></span></a>

        </div><!-- end myCarousel -->

        <div class="row" id="FroYo">

            <a href="#"><img src="img/contact-para-bg.png" alt="Bots"</a>


</body>
</html>

CSS:

/* --------------------------------------
   Layout
   -------------------------------------- */

   .nav-bar {


        position:fixed;

        top:0;

        background-color:white;

        padding-top:30px;

        padding-left:100px;
   }

   .navbar-brand {

    padding: 13px 15px;

    background-color:white;
}


   .icons {

        margin:0;

        padding-top: 25px;

        padding-right: 200px;

        padding-left:100px;

        background-color:white;


    }

    .icons a{

        font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;

        text-decoration: none;

        float: left;

        display: block;

        padding: 20px 15px;

        color:gray;

        background-color:white;

    }

    .icons a:hover{

        color:purple;
    }





* --------------------------------------
   Carousel
   -------------------------------------- */

#myCarousel {
    margin-top: 300px;
    background-color:gray;
}

.carousel-caption {
    font-size: 24px;
}

.carousel-caption h4 {
    font-size: 32px;

}


#myCarousel .item { height: 700px; }

#slide1 {
    background: url('../img/best-slide.png') top center no-repeat;
}

#slide2 {
    background: url('../img/good.png') top center no-repeat;
}

#slide3 {
    background: url('../img/slide3.png') top center no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can throw a bottom border on the navbar and modify the css of the border to make the space between the navbar and the rest of your page.  You also forgot the `data-ride="carousel"` in the div tag for the carousel.